# Using promise after iteration is finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am trying to figure out how implement an asynchronous way of executing after an iteration is done

Essentially I have something like this:

```
  data.businesses.map( club => {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/club/${currentEmail}/${club.id}`)
      .then( ({data}) => {
        placeholder.push( Object.assign({}, club, data))
      })
      .then( () => ..do extra stuff )
  })

  // when data.businesses.map is done iterating all of the elements, do something
```

As you can see, there is some asynchronous issue when retrieving fetching information via `axios`

I'm still new to the idea of `Promises` but I am not sure where to apply, if it applicable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for a collection of promises to resolve (or at least one to reject) using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

To gather that collection, you can have the iterator function for `.map()` return each Promise by removing the braces from the arrow function.

```
let promisedClubs = data.businesses.map( club =>
  axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/club/${currentEmail}/${club.id}`)
    .then( ({data}) => {
      placeholder.push( Object.assign({}, club, data))
    })
    .then( () => ..do extra stuff )
);

Promise.all(promisedClubs).then(clubs => {
    // when data.businesses.map is done iterating all of the elements, do something
}, failedClub => {
    // error handling
});
```

Comment: Awesome, I didnt know about `Promise.all()` Thanks!!